# Create an intent filter for app's internal use

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to create an Activity with an `intent-filter` for sharing images.
But I want that activity only to be available when the share intent comes from my own application, that is:

- If a share intent is launched from other app, my ShareActivity does not appear in the intent chooser
- If a share intent is launched from my app, the ShareActivity appears within the rest of share targets like Gmail, SMS, etc.

I have tried setting the `exported=false` but it is still accesible from outside

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ShareTestActivity"
        android:label="ShareTest"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How can I solve that? Thank you

Comment: I already ranted to Google about their practice of ignoring exported status/permissions with respect to your scenario, and I was told it is working as intended. So, while IMHO your approach would work, it won't. That being said, [`EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS) should allow you to add in your activity, assuming that you are using `Intent.createChooser()` to launch the `ACTION_SEND` options. Get rid of your `<intent-filter>` and use an explicit `Intent` to your activity in the array for `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. With that approach the EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS activities appear in front of the other, I'd like to have all the options at the same level, keeping the alphabetical order, etc. How can I combine both intents?

Comment: AFAIK, you would have to implement your own chooser, using `PackageManager`, `queryIntentActivities()`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve what you are looking for is to effectively create your own chooser. And build it the way you want it. What you'd also have to do is also change the action to be com.myapp.action.SEND (or other some unique action) so that **YOU** can explicitly handle that intent.

When you get that intent, then build the chooser the way you want. Which is to query the original android.intent.action.SEND + the other data and then build the data to attach to your chooser. Using Intent.createChooser() when you need to.